# TexShop not compiling for all users on a machine using Big Sur 11.1

Tags: texshop, macos

After installing MacOS 11.1 Big Sur, I upgraded TeXShop and MacTex (Basic is not sufficient). There are 3 tex users on this machine and TeXShop works well for two of them. For the 3rd, TeXShop opens as usual and the console pops open when attempting to compile, but that's the end - no compiling occurs. Compiling via the command line (terminal) works as expected for all users. What could be the cause and what might be a solution?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Do the users' permissions to access various folders the TeX system differ?

Answer (score 0):

I just hit this myself. Upgrading to the 2021 TeXLive distribution and then adding /usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/universal-darwin/ to my PATH did the trick.